# How to access element zero in HQL?

Tags: hql

I have the Entity and NamedQuery:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="myQuery", query="select m from MyEntity m where m.child.x = 7"
})
public class MyClass {

    @Column(name="CHILD_COL")
    private Child child;
    // getter and setter

}

public class Child {
 int x;
 // getter and setter
}
```

Now, I want to change it to have a list o Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="myQuery", query="select m from MyEntity m where m.childs[0].x = 7"
})
public class MyClass {

    @Column(name="CHILD_COL")
    private List<Child> childs;
    // getter and setter

}
```

But but the 'childs[0].x' syntax does not exist. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Indexed lists are supporterd by Hibernate but is important the definition.

In old way (XML mapping) you can work as follow:

In pojo:

```
private List<Child> childs;
```

In XML mapping:

```
<list name="childs" table="yourtable" cascade="all,delete-orphan"  
    inverse="false" lazy="false">
     <key column="fk_to_parent"/>
     <list-index column="an_integer_column"/>
      <one-to-many class="Child" />
</list>
```

In JPA annotation you must use `IndexColumn` annotation as follow:

```
@IndexColumn(name="an_integer_column", base=0, nullable=false)
```

So you'll have:

```
@Column(name="CHILD_COL")
@IndexColumn(name="an_integer_column", base=0, nullable=false)
private List<Child> childs;
```

Tell me if it's OK